# csrf token Follow up

Tags: python, django, django-csrf

Hello and thank you in advance.  This is a follow up question from the following thread (not sure if I should have posted there or started a new thread...:

[CSRF token missing or incorrect even though I have {% csrf_token %}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922773/csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect-even-though-i-have-csrf-token)

I am not sure what I need to do with the code to make csrfContext work.  I am trying to use ModelForm to collect data to a model and write it to a MYSQL table.  I am gettingthe error:

```
Reason given for failure:
    CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

Here is the code:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
    from djengo.template import RequestContext
    from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpRequest, HttpResponseRedirect
    from acmetest.models import Player
    from acmetest.models import PickForm

    csrfContext = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response('makepick.html', csrfContext)

    def playerAdd(request, id=None):
        form = PickForm(request.POST or None,
                           instance=id and Player.objects.get(id=id))

        # Save new/edited pick
        if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/draft/')

        return render_to_response('makepick.html', {'form':form})
```

Again,

Thank you for your help!

dpbklyn

Comment: Just saw this addon-question. Not sure how/why the answer helped, but one thing I have to mention - assuming you cut/paste the code exactly, you misspelled `django.template` as `djengo.template`. It isn't *invalid* code, just typo'ed. (And you should be using RequestContext, if you're not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code thusly:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# from djengo.template import RequestContext <- this is not valid.
```

These two lines, as Yuji pointed out, are not valid python, and in addition they are not necessary if you use the [`render`](http://django.me/render) shortcut.

```
# csrfContext = RequestContext(request)
# return render_to_response('makepick.html', csrfContext)
```

Modify your return line:

```
 # return render_to_response('makepick.html', {'form':form})
   return render(request,'makepick.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: Thank you!  I am not sure I am clear though...I though that csrf was necessary for security purposes.  Also, in the <form> block on the HTML template, I assume I don't need the <% csfr_token %> an I correct?

Comment: You always need `{% csrf_token %}` if you use `POST` with forms that are submitting to your views (unless you explicitly mark your views as [exempt from csrf](http://django.me/csrf_exempt)).

The [`render`](http://django.me/render) shortcut takes care of the `RequestContext` requirements for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming we're talking about the `playerAdd` view - you need to pass `RequestContext` to the response there.

```
def playerAdd(request, id=None):
    form = PickForm(request.POST or None,
                       instance=id and Player.objects.get(id=id))
    # Save new/edited pick
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/draft/')

    return render_to_response('makepick.html', RequestContext(request, {'form':form}))
```

The first lines in your code are hard to understand and doesn't even appear to be valid python. You can't use `return` from outside a function block.

Comment: Shouldn't the `dict` be outside the `RequestContext` and the `render_to_response` be `render_to_response('makepick.html', {'form':form}, RequestContext(request))`

Comment: @SandipAgarwal it's a `Context` subclass so it works.. Which do you like better? I think passing RC as the context dict is more intuitive

Comment: Ok. Which is a more efficient way?